# What does the standalone '-' option do in Linux/tar?

Tags: linux, pipe, tar

I came across the following command syntax in GNU tar. There are even examples of this on the tar [manpage](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html). However, I did not find an explanation of what the standalone `-` option does. I suspect it has something to do with piping the output to . Can anyone elaborate? Is this specific to tar or is this a general Linux feature?

```
tar -cf - <directory> | <somecommand>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the dash `-` as a filename to mean the standard input or standard output is a convention that a lot of programs use (e.g. `cat`, `tar`, etc). It is not a special property of the filename. Specifically when redirecting, `-` is not recognised as a special filename, so your shell will use that as the literal filename.

Comment: That makes sense! No wonder it was so hard to search for this "option"!